# SQL find rows whose column "tag" contains a tag

Tags: php, mysql, tags

I have a table for articles. Its major fields are:

```
id
article_name
content
tags (its values will be comma seperate example test, abc ...)
```

Now when I am on a detail page of any article. I want to show related article in my sidebar. For this if any other article uses the same tag as current article. I want to list those articles as related article. This is my query.

Can anyone please help me on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
select.....
where  find_in_set(current article name,name of column)
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

For minimum coding you can use [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function.

```
 SELECT FIND_IN_SET('b','a,b,c,d');
```

But next time consider using an additional table to store each tag in separate record